# Shopify - Firefox CSS columns dont look right

Tags: html, css, shopify

I have a webshop with Shopify. There seems to be a problem with the placement of products only on one page. I've tried with some simple CSS but it didnt help.

[Link to problem](http://chateau-clothing.myshopify.com/collections/long-sleeves)

In Chrome and other browsers it looks fine.

Have a great one!

Comment: I don't see the problem (yes I use FF). Maybe you should explain the problem better and add some relevant html and css code. What was that simple css what didn't help?

Comment: Might this be a means to promote the shop? Then this is spam...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to centre the two products?
Ff that is the case remove `float:none` on `.product-grid .product-item (line : 1324)`, then add `large-offset-3` as a class on the first product item.